# How to decode information from the serial port using arduino and pyserial

Tags: python, arduino, serial-port, pyserial

I want to read the information that I send through the serial port with Arduino. For that, I use pyserial, initialize the port and then try to read the information.

This is the Arduino code

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println("1");
}
```

This is the python code

```
import serial
ComPort = "com3"
try:
    SerialComs = serial.Serial(ComPort, 9600)  # Intializes the Com port
except:
    pass

while True:
    for i in range(1):
        data = 0
        value = SerialComs.readline() 
        print(value)
```

The output that I get is this:

b'1\r\n'

To get only the number 1, which is what I want, I tried this:

```
import serial
ComPort = "com3"
try:
    SerialComs = serial.Serial(ComPort, 9600)  # Intializes the Com port
except:
    pass

while True:
    for i in range(1):
        data = 0
        value = int(SerialComs.readline().decode('ascii'))
        print(value)
```

but I get this error

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xb1 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

What can I do to get only the number from the serial port?

Answer (score 1):

The quick answer is to add `errors='ignore'` to your decode line. e.g.

```
value = SerialComs.readline().decode(encoding='ascii', errors='ignore')
```

This will stop the code exiting with an error because of invalid ASCII characters in the readline.

This will still give an error when you convert to an integer because there will be invalid content in the string so you would need to check that your content in a digit. e.g.

```py
readline_data0 = [b"\x00\x00\xf01\r\n",
                  b"1\r\n",
                  b"1\r\n",
                  b"1\r\n"]

for line in readline_data0:
    txt = "".join(
        [x for x in line.decode(encoding="ascii", errors="ignore") if x.isdigit()]
    )
    value = int(txt)
    print(value)
```

Would give the output:

```
1
1
1
1
```

This might be quite error prone if you are not certain what is coming in on the serial port.

To mitigate this issue, a more verbose message from the Arduino would help identify which is the intended data. For example if the message from the Aruino was based on comma separated values it might look like: `Serial.println(",sensor1,1,");`

An example of how this could be easily extracted from the serial content:

```py
readline_data1 = [b"\x00\x00\xf0,sensor1,1,\r\n",
                  b",sensor1,1,\r\n",
                  b",sensor1,1,\r\n",
                  b",sensor1,1,\r\n"]


def get_sensor_value(sensor_name, ascii_data):
    fields = ascii_data.split(',')
    sensor_loc = fields.index(sensor_name) + 1
    return int(fields[sensor_loc])


for line in readline_data1:
    txt = line.decode(encoding="ascii", errors="ignore")
    value = get_sensor_value('sensor1', txt)
    print(value)
```

Which gave the output:

```
1
1
1
1
```

This also has the benefit that it can be extended to send data from multiple sensors as the values can be associated with a particular sensor.

```py
readline_data1 = [b"\x00\x00\xf0,sensor1,1,\r\n",
                  b",sensor1,1,sensor3,3,\r\n",
                  b",sensor2,2,\r\n",
                  b",sensor1,1,\r\n"]


def get_sensor_value(sensor_name, ascii_data):
    fields = ascii_data.split(',')
    if sensor_name not in fields:
        return
    sensor_loc = fields.index(sensor_name) + 1
    return int(fields[sensor_loc])


for line in readline_data1:
    txt = line.decode(encoding="ascii", errors="ignore")
    for check_sensor in ['sensor1', 'sensor2', 'sensor3']:
        value = get_sensor_value(check_sensor, txt)
        if value:
            print(f"{check_sensor} = {value}")
```

Which gave the output:

```
sensor1 = 1
sensor1 = 1
sensor3 = 3
sensor2 = 2
sensor1 = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If all the lines will be `int`, then you need some steps:

```py
value = SerialComs.readline()
value = value.decode()   # convert from bytes -> str
value = value.strip()    # remove line endings
value = int(value)       # convert str -> in
print(value)
```

Done all in one:

```py
value = int(SerialComs.readline().decode().strip())
print(value)
```

If you have trouble with non-ascii bytes getting into the serial stream you will have to filter them out:

```py
value = bytes([v for v in SerialComs.readline() if v in range(1,127)])
value = int(value.decode().strip())
print(value)
```

Comment: It worked the first time I tried. However, sometimes when I run the code I get this error

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte

Comment: Its difficult to tell where that data is coming from. Perhaps you could run this a few more times and have: `value = SerialComs.readline();print(value)` and tell me what you see. Is it to do with power cycling the Arduino?

Comment: This is the output when I run it:

b'\x00\x00\xf01\r\n'

b'1\r\n'

b'1\r\n'

b'1\r\n'

And yes, the idea is to do it with power cycling the Arduino as I want to connect a sensor and get that data in python

Answer (score 0):

Andrés , based on your comment to @quamrana answer, with regard to the bytes sequence: `b'\x00\x00\xf01\r\n'`, in my opinion, the `\x00\x00\xf0` are spurious bytes that somehow made it into the serial data stream, maybe as noise that has come onto the data line.

If on the Arduino, you only ran `Serial.println("1");` as you say you did, then the 3 bytes represented by `"1\r\n"` should be the only bytes sent through the Serial data stream.

I might check for any loose wires/connections, grounding issues, or try a different cable.